# Installing IBM Lotus Symphony Dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, ibm-lotus-symphony

Im having troubles finding the answer to my questions, even in the IBM lotus symphony website so if you can help me it would be great :)

How do i can install the spanish Dictionary?  and Where i can download it?

Comment: Close voters:  This question has a good answer and **should not** be closed.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [IBM Lotus Symphony Installation Guide](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/lotus/symphony/help.nsf/InstallGuide?OpenForm&version=3.0.1) they offer a `.deb` package for installation on Ubuntu, that can be easily installed graphically (GUI) or Terminal, the problem is that the package is designed for Ubuntu 10.04, but if you really want to install it, follow this instructions:

### Graphically

- Download the package;
- Double click it and follow the steps.

### From the Terminal

- Use the `cd` to access the download directory.
- At the download directory type the following command and replace the "[package_name.deb]" with the package name with its extension:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i [package_name.deb]
  ```
- If the installation failed because of unmet dependencies look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) for information on how to fix this type of problem.